# What's the most straightforward way to share an iOS app development build?

Tags: ios, debugging, mobile, deployment, build

I'm developing a mobile app (using React Native for that matter), and I'd like to have one of the members of my team try it out.

With Android, I can just share the apk with them. Is there something similiar in iOS?

Comment: Haven't tried, but maybe you could do something like [How to share a compiled iOS app ipa with your users for testing using Dropbox or your website](https://solarianprogrammer.com/2016/05/14/how-to-share-ios-app-ipa-with-users-for-testing-using-dropbox-or-your-website/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a bunch of tools to do this. Test Flight is not the easiest way to share a build because you need to submit it to the app store, it needs to be processed, pass through all the checks before someone can download it. 
Whilst you should definitely use Test Flight to deploy official test versions, an internally used tool for alpha and beta versions is quicker and easier.

I would suggest a tool like [Fabric Beta](https://get.fabric.io/) (currently owned by Google), which is a free app deployment + analytics tool. you will need to add some code to allow it to work but it is a simple process. It comes with a program to help deploy and you can plug it into most CI software.

You will need to ensure you have the device UUID's of people in your internal team to sign the application for their devices.

Comment: Arguably, your proposed method is no more *straightforward* than mine.. perhaps even less, actually.

Comment: Might not be any better in setup, but in terms of quick releases, you can release a lot of builds quickly without any processing time and have versions ready to install as soon as they're uploaded, no processing, no waiting, no checks, no forgetting to bump the version and getting rejected, apple made ad hoc builds for a reason.

Answer (score 0):

[Test Flight](https://developer.apple.com/testflight/) is what you're looking for.

First though you need to add the UDID of your team member's device to the provisioning profile used to create the .ipa (iOS equivalent of an APK). But after that, just follow the information and tutorial(s) at the provided link.